# Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed

Tags: react, react-native

Atualizei meu projeto react native da versão 0.57.8 para a última versão e estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem de aviso:

```
Warning: componentWillMount has been renamed, and is not recommended for use. See https://fb.me/react-async-component-lifecycle-hooks for details.
```

Eu entrei nesse link que aparece [Update on Async Rendering](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html)

Executei o comando recomendado no tutorial:

```
cd your_project
npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles
```

No tutorial segundo o que li, parece que esse comando é para atualizar as funcções componentWillMount, componentWillUpdate, etc. Porém ainda continuo recebendo a mesma mensagem de aviso.

Alguém pode me ajudar a corrigir isso?

Comment: Os métodos `componentWillMount ` foram renomeados para `componentDidMount`?

Comment: In my case, the problem was happen because I'm trying to load a qr code inside the Storybook. So, I created a boolean state to identify when the scenario is a SB and apply a fake qr code (a generated image) and when it's in production, the real qr code will be called. Works great for me. *** No meu caso, o problema aconteceu porque estou tentando carregar um código qr dentro do Storybook. Então, criei um estado booleano para identificar quando o cenário é um SB e aplicar um código qr falso (uma imagem gerada) e quando estiver em produção, o código qr real será chamado. Funciona muito bem para

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/blog/2019/08/08/react-v16.9.0.html) do React alguns métodos do ciclo de vida de um componente React serão descontinuados, eles recomandam utilizar o [npm codemod](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-codemod) para renomear esse métodos.

Passos:

- `npm i -g react-codemod`
- `cd seuProjeto`
- `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles`

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado.